# cypress run throws Webpack Compilation Error but cypress open is able to run normally

Tags: cypress

Cypress runs perfectly from the UI, but fails to run via the CI using `cypress run`

When I attempt to run it I get the following error:

```
Oops...we found an error preparing this test file:

  > cypress\support\e2e.ts

The error was:

Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/core/lib-esm/Signer.js
```

The error is actually SUPER long, but it just lists the cascade of additional failures to follow. If there's a need, I'll add more of it.

Anyone has any idea what's going on? What additional information might I provide?

Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No.... Unfortunately I hadn't figured it out